# The spherical coordinates of $(-3, 4, -12)$ are $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. Find $\tan \theta + \tan \phi$.

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

The spherical coordinates of $(-3, 4, -12)$ are $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. Find $\tan (\theta )+ \tan( \phi)$.

I've already tried converting the Cartesian coordinates provided into spherical coordinates:

I got $\rho= 13$, $\theta = \arccos(-12/13)$, and $\phi = \arctan(-4/3)$

I'm not sure how to add theta and phi together, I'm not sure if I converted them correctly at all.

Answer (score 1):

If $$x=r \sin \theta  \cos \phi$$
$$y=r \sin \theta  \sin \phi$$
$$z = r \cos \theta$$
Where $\theta \in [0, \pi] $ is angle between axis $z$ and interval ended in point in question and $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$ is angle between $x$ axis and projection of point on $xy$ plane.Then we have
$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$\theta= \arctan \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z} = \arccos \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
$$\phi = \arctan \frac{y}{x}$$

Comment: Oh sorry if you misread the question, but I need to find tan(θ)+tan(ϕ)., not only convert it to spherical coordinates.

Comment: I added in answer, for your convenience, definition for angle-s, to make for you more easy to see triangles and calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a 'triangle' with $\cos(\theta)=-12/13$ (the one side will be negative, but this is fine); what is $\tan(\theta)$ in this triangle? Also, if $\phi = \arctan(-4/3)$, what is $\tan(\phi)$?

Comment: Is $\tan \theta = -5/12$? and the second one I got -3/4, however somebody else told me that is wrong but I thought arctan was just the reciprocal of tan, so I'm not sure how to convert arctan to tan.

Comment: Arctan is the *function inverse* of tangent. For instance, $\arctan(1)=\pi/4$, because $\tan(\pi/4)=1$.

Comment: So $\tan \phi = -4/3$?